# What is the complexity of for loop that is dividing by half and then behaving like logn?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
for(int i=n/2; i>=1 ; i=i/2)
statement1;
```

What is the Worst case (big-o) of this loop? I have examined it, So, i got these results:

If N =100, it will divide the N to half, 50, After that , it will start logn behaviour, like , 50,25,12,6,3,1. Same thing precisely elaborated below:

1. if N=100 => N/2 => N=50
2. N=50 => 50,25,12,6,3,1

From above results, i got to know that,  1st line is giving N/2, which mean, O(N), and next line is behaving like Log(N). Two things can happened.

- it can be O(logn)
- it can be less than O(logn)

Comment: What do you mean when you write : `it will start logn behaviour, like , 50,25,12,6,3,1` ?

Comment: It will start behaviour like logn because of i=i*2, After cutting from half because of i<=N/2

Comment: What you say is sometimes a bit imprecise, but you are right that `statement1` is executed O(log n) times.

Comment: But your `ì` variable is going up isn't it ? And you `N` variable is not changing. I don't understand what these numbers (50, 25, 12...) refer to...

Comment: @JawwadRafiq, I perfectly know what is a logarithmic complexity, I'm just not sure what your numbers `50, 25, 12 ...` refer to.

Comment: oh i got it. you can think it as,  1,2,4,8,16,32,....
I have written there in descending order.

Comment: You can't edit the code to change the core part of the question completely. This is a waste of time.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, It doesn't matter, Just changing the order. It is same like it was before.

Comment: Problem complexity has not changed, but the problem did change - every single part of the `for `loop is new, and the sequence of values of `i` is different. I'm happy that you have your answer, though.

Comment: You have removed your answer. I was going to tick it. Sorry for it. really sorry. I can remove question if you felt it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This thing actually i wanted to ask. "If a problem is O(n), half the problem is also O(n). If a problem is O(log n), half the problem is also O(log n)"
its mean,

- Division of loop wont effect the total size. It will remain O(n)
- after that, i=i/2, will give the complexity O(logn).